# Cocos2D + Storyboards, implement Play Again feature and reload the game scene

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I integrated a Cocos2d Game in a storyboard project. Below is the storyboard. When the game finishes (`onExit` method) I send a notification to the `CocosViewController` and perform a segue from there, which opens `ScoreViewController`. This is working fine. Moreover, I want to load the game again when when the user press the *"Play Again"* Button in `ScoreViewController`.

I tried with an unwind segue and it opens `CocosViewController` but it does not load the game, it returns immediately to `ScoreViewController`. How can implement the Play Again feature? Perhaps with a segue?

[image]

CocosViewController

```
 -(void)setupCocos2d {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    //[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden:YES];


    if([director isViewLoaded] == NO)
    {
    // Create the OpenGL view that Cocos2D will render to.
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

        // Assign the view to the director.
        director.view = glView;


        // Initialize other director settings.
        [director setAnimationInterval:1.0f/60.0f];
        [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
    }

    // Set the view controller as the director's delegate, so we can respond to certain events.
    director.delegate = self;

    // Add the director as a child view controller of this view controller.
    [self addChildViewController:director];


    // Add the director's OpenGL view as a subview so we can see it.
    [self.view addSubview:director.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:director.view];

    // Finish up our view controller containment responsibilities.
    [director didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Run whatever scene we'd like to run here.
    NSArray *parameters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3", @"sound", @"countdown", nil];

    if(director.runningScene)
        [director replaceScene:[IntroLayer sceneWithParameters:parameters]];
    else
        [director pushScene:[IntroLayer sceneWithParameters:parameters]];

}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self setupCocos2d];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationFromGame:) name:@"GameEndedNotification" object:nil];
}


-(void)receiveNotificationFromGame:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"GameEndedNotification"])
    {
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification! %@", [self class]);
        NSLog(@"score: %d", [notification.userInfo[@"score"] intValue]);

        //get variables
        score = [notification.userInfo[@"score"] intValue];
        gameTracking = notification.userInfo[@"gameTracking"];

        //show the next view
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sg_showScore" sender:self];
    }
}

- (IBAction)unwindToCocosViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender {
    //nothing goes there
}
```

This is how I initialize the cocos2d game:

```
-(id) initWithParameters:(NSArray *) parameters
{
    NSLog(@"init TheButton with parameters");

    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

   gameParameters = parameters;

    // Enable touch handling on scene node
    [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];

    // Create a colored background (Dark Grey)
    //CCNodeColor *background = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.6f blue:0.6f alpha:1.0f]];
    //[self addChild:background];

    CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.png" selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.png"
                                target:self selector:@selector(increasePoints:)];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    starMenuItem.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
    starMenuItem.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
    starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu];

    timeLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0.00" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18.0f];
    //timeLabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    timeLabel.position = ccp(30,size.height-10);
    // Add the time label
    [self addChild:timeLabel];
    NSLog(@"time: %@", [gameParameters objectAtIndex:0]);

    clicksLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18.0f];
    //clicksLabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    clicksLabel.position = ccp(size.width - 20,size.height-10);
    // Add the time label
    [self addChild:clicksLabel];

    [self startGame];

    return self;
}


-(void) startGame
{
    clicks = 0;
    myTime = [[gameParameters objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

    [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to re-add glView within `-setupCocos2d`, since it has been already added. I'm not sure if it is the only reason of wrong behavior, but try to put this method call from `viewDidAppear` to `-viewDidLoad`, and when returning back from `ScoreViewController`, just reset your Cocos2d engine (e.g. clear all labels or remove enemies) without recreating view.

However, your approach is not very good, I strongly recommend you to make all scenes with Cocos2d, not with UIViewControllers. There are nice transitions between scenes too (at least, within Cocos2d 3.0).

Comment: I put the method in viewDidLoad but now the scene is portrait and not landscape. Also, how can I reset the Cocos2d engine? It loads the scene but the countdown is 0 and the score is the same when I finished.

Comment: @nabrugir that what I meant by "reset engine" - setting score to 0, starting countdown from the beginning and everything else you've done before game started. Not sure why the orientation has changed.

Comment: From where should I do this? from cocosviewcontroller or from the game? Could you give me an example?

Comment: @nabrugir I don't know how you are setting your score. What do you do in the start of the game to set the countdown and score to appropriate values? You should do exactly the same after "Play again" button is hit

Comment: I added the source code in the question. However the main problem is I don't know how to call [self startgame] when the game is loaded the second time, since both onEnter and initWithParameters are not called.